# Can not insert a string in a http get request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, parameters, routes

In the input field specific id will be typed and saved inside `searchText` :

```
<form class="input-group" ng-submit="getMainData()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText"  placeholder=" Type KvK-nummer and Press Enter" id="typehead">
</form>
```

and when press enter it will get this function from the controller

```
$scope.getMainData = function(){    
 $http.get("http://localhost:8091/odata/dll-poc-dv/Account(':searchText')")
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.allData = data;
            $scope.getData = $scope.allData.d.results;
        });
    };
```

What I want to achieve is the `searchText` typed in the input to be passed as parameter inside the brackets (':searchText') of get the relevant data. A valid URL for getting the data looks like this: `http://localhost:8091/odata/dll-poc-dv/Account('41-125061-0000')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+` operator for concatenation of variables. Also, use `$scope.searchText`.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8091/odata/dll-poc-dv/Account('" + $scope.searchText + "')")
```